# What is the best way to parse JsonObject containing just one enormous JsonObject (Gson)

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

I have a Json of this type :

```
{
"4f958ef28ecd651095af6ab6": {
     enormous JsonObject
}
}
```

the "4f958ef28ecd651095af6ab6" is different each time (but I know what it will be as it is a parameter of my api call), it corresponds to the id of the following object. I have a Gson-configured model to parse the enormous JsonObject.

My question is : is it performant to use simply

```
new JSONObject(jsonresponse).getJSONObject("4f958ef28ecd651095af6ab6")
```

and parse with Gson from there ?
Is there a better way to do so ?

I guess the real question would be, what does "new JSONObject(String)" realy do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is:

- You load all the Json string into the phone memory (memory issue + long time to load entirely)
- You create a big `JSONObject` (same issues) in order to have access to each key.

You write few code but this is not the most performant solution.

To minimized the memory impact and accelerate the operation of objects' creation, you can use Gson in [stream mode](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming).

By directly read the input stream, you avoid to load too much data and you can directly start to populate your object piece by piece.

And about the `JSONObject`, it will mostly check if your json string is correct (or it will throw a `JsonException`) and it will let you look into the object when you search for a key and its value.

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for. Stream mode it will be

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use hybrid (native and gson) since i am not sure how to get unknown jsonobject with GSON.

You need to get your response as a [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html), then itarete for each [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html). You can experiment parsing code as trying. Please check `JSONArray.getJSONObject(int index)` method. Then we can use GSON to get our data model to get known attributes.

If you can post complete json data, we can give it chance to parse together.

Comment: this is basicly the entire JSONObject, I think I don't need to use JSONArray. The solution I posted works well, but I was wondering if I could do better.

Comment: How did you mind that you can get JSONObject if you dont know the id name which is "4f958ef28ecd651095af6ab6"?

Comment: I have the id (basicly this json is the response i get when i call a webservice with this id), sorry I should have been clearer.